# Permissions on newly created files and nested shared folders

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, file-sharing

On OS X Mountain Lion, I use two accounts (login users); one which is my primary account and the other which I created to share a Google Drive folder with the primary, since the latter also have an active Google Drive app running.

I always login to both accounts, so that the files and changes to the Google Drive files accessed through the shared folder on my primary account are updated to the web through the app running on the secondary logged account.

The issue I am having is that whenever a new file or folder is created in the shared Google Drive folder through the primary account, said files and folders are created with the permissions of the primary and not the secondary account, therefore the Google Drive app running on the secondary account can't read them and update the web.

I don't want to be in the need to constantly clicking the Apply Permissions to all nested folders (cmd - I), and what I am looking for is a way to have OS X automatically enforce the permissions policy of the secondary account on its shared folder when files are added through the primary account.

If there is not a native OS X function available easily for this, I will like to automate this through a Hazel rule or similar, so that it check for changes and enforce the permissions policy.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain how this will interact with Google Drive, but generally the best way to give several users consistent access to everything in a folder is to create a group (in the Users & Groups preference pane), add the relevant users to it, then add inheritable access control entry to the folder and its current contents:

```
sudo chmod -R +a "group:examplegroup allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /path/to/folder
```

See [this answer on apple.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31438/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-a-mac-to-make-new-files-inherit-parent-directory-permissio/31448#31448) for more details.